# How to show custom error messages using passport and express

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I check if the email already exist when registering a user. If a user already exist I pass the error message "email already exists". But in the front end it shows "Unauthorized" error 401. I want to pass the error message which I pass to the front end from the back end but it pass the default message. below is how I check if a user already exist and send the error message,

```
exports.register = new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done,res) {
    var newUser = new User({
        email: email,
        password: password,
        name: req.body.fname
    });
    var searchUser = {
        email: email
    };
    User.findOne(searchUser, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        console.log("err "+err);

        if (user) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: "email already exists"
            });
        }
        newUser.save(function(err) {
        console.log("newUser "+newUser);
            done(null, newUser);
        })
    });
});
```

I use passport for authentication,

```
authRouter.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-register'),function(req, res) {
    createSendToken(req.user, res);
});
```

The error message is not the one I pass to the front end. It shows unauthorized error, which is the default error. When I print the error message in the console in front end it shows,

```
Object {data: "Unauthorized", status: 401, config: Object, statusText: "Unauthorized"}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are not saying what output you want in your front end, but I'm guessing you want to have `data` to be the `message` that you set in your `LocalStrategy`.

Here is one way to do that:

```
authRouter.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local-register', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { 
        res.status(401);
        res.end(info.message);
        return;
    }
    createSendToken(req.user, res);
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can take advantage of `passReqToCallback: true` in [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authorize/).

> With this option enabled, **`req`** will be passed as the first argument to the verify callback.

Also by taking advantage of [flash messages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash).

Here is basic example of how you use it,

```
// your strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
    (req, username, password, done) => {
      User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) done(err)
        if (!user) {
          console.log('user does not exists')
          return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'User does not exist' ))
        } else {
          console.log('user exists')
          return done(null, user, req.flash('message', 'User exist'))
        }
      })
    }
  ))
```

---

```
// your GET login
router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  var message = req.flash('message')
  res.render("pages/login", { message })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers you can manually check the `info` parameter and then return your own message based on that:

```js
// ❌ MESSY ❌
authRouter.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-register', function(err, user, info) {
        if(info.name === 'UserExistsError' ) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: "Email already exists"
            });
        } else if (info.name === 'IncorrectUsernameError') {
          return done(null, false, {
              message: "Email does not exist"
          });
        } else if(....
```

But A **MUCH** cleaner way is to just specify custom error messages when you create the `Account` Mongoose model:

```js
var Account = new Schema({
    ...
});

var options = {
    errorMessages: {
        UserExistsError: 'Email already exists',
        IncorrectUsernameError: 'Email does not exist',
        IncorrectPasswordError: ...
    }
};

Account.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, options);
```

Then in your signup route you can simply return the `info.message` to the user.

```js
// ✨ CLEAN ✨
authRouter.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-register', function(err, user, info) {
        return done(null, false, {
            message: info.message
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using passReqToCallback = true then you can send it just like

```
if (!isMatch) { return done({ message: 'Incorrect password' }); }
```